# Insert Now() into MYSQL

Tags: html, mysql, jsp

I'm trying to insert the current date and time into MYSQL from a `.jsp` but my code won't work. Why? I don't have time set-up as a variable because I assume the `jsp` will get the current/date as records are being loaded into the DB. I hope I've explain enough.

```
String insert1 = ("insert into ticket (t_date,t_equipment, t_descript,emp_id,tech_id)"
+ " values( now(),'"+a+"', '"+b+"', '"+c+"', '"+j+"')");
```

Also for the foreign key `emp_id`, do I need to specify the table name (`employee.emp_id`) in the insert statement or leave it as is since I've already created `emp_id` as a FK in ticket table in the database?

Table code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `helpdesk`.`Ticket` (
  `T_ID` INT () NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_date` DATETIME NULL,
  `t_equipment` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `t_descript` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`T_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `emp_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `helpdesk`.`employee` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `tech_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `helpdesk`.`technician` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is the output that I get:

Executed the following SQL statement:

```
insert into ticket (t_date,t_equipment, t_descript,emp_id,tech_id)
values(now(),'laptop', 'Can't access the network', '77777', '12344')
insert into employee (emp_id, emp_fname,emp_lname,emp_email, emp_phone,emp_cellphone,emp_dept)
values ('77777','Cassie','Somers','csomers@biz.org','2487775555','2487775551','null')
```

Ouch, an SQLException was thrown..

`.jsp` code:

```
String insert1 = ("insert into ticket (t_date,t_equipment, t_descript,emp_id,tech_id)" + 
"values(now(),'"+a+"', '"+b+"', '"+c+"', '"+j+"')");

String insert2 = ("insert into employee (emp_id, emp_fname,emp_lname,emp_email, emp_phone,emp_cellphone,emp_dept)" +
"values ('"+c+"','"+ d+"','"+e+"','"+f+"','"+g+"','"+h+"','"+i+"')");
```

Comment: What does it do instead of work? What error do you receive? Is `t_date` a proper MySQL `DATE/DATETIME` data type in your table? (you don't need to specify the FK table name because you aren't inserting anything into that table - you are inserting into `ticket`)

Comment: yes, it is set up as a date data type in the table. I posted the table code above.

Comment: Are you certain you are executing this code? (and not some earlier version) Using `NOW()` in the context you did is valid and correct. Print the contents of `insert1` to make sure it looks like you expect it to.

Comment: Yes, I've added my output above and now that I've check the database, nothing is actually in the tables. I'm not sure what happened.

Comment: Unless I'm drunk, you can't insert into FK's. You need separate statements to make inserts into referenced tables.

Comment: Unless you are writing this out in a loop, I see _two insert statements_ without any delimiter between them. Are you trying to do two inserts in `insert1`?

Comment: @kermit Well,why does it say the value for emp_id was inserted into for ticket table? emp_id is a FK for the ticket table.

Comment: Yes,@MichaelBerkowski - two inserts they are in a delimiter <% %>  with the rest of the code...I was trying not to overwhelm you all with a bunch of code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message & queries, does the database setting for `t_date` is `DATETIME`, but [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) returns a format that matches `TIMESTAMP`. So you can change your `CREATE TABLE` to be something like this so the default of `t_date` is always `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `helpdesk`.`Ticket` (
  `T_ID` INT () NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_date` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `t_equipment` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `t_descript` VARCHAR(300) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`T_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `emp_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `helpdesk`.`employee` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `tech_id`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `helpdesk`.`technician` ()
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

And then your query can just drop the `NOW()` completely like so:

```
String insert1 = ("insert into ticket (t_date,t_equipment, t_descript,emp_id,tech_id)"
+ " values('','"+a+"', '"+b+"', '"+c+"', '"+j+"')");
```

But that said there is another major issue: the `INSERT` you show is formatted like this:

```
insert into ticket (t_date,t_equipment, t_descript,emp_id,tech_id)
values(now(),'laptop', 'Can't access the network', '77777', '12344')
insert into employee (emp_id, emp_fname,emp_lname,emp_email, emp_phone,emp_cellphone,emp_dept)
values ('77777','Cassie','Somers','csomers@biz.org','2487775555','2487775551','null')
```

But the word `Can't` has a single quote in it (`'`) which closes the string value. So you should be use the Java equivalent of the PHP [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) on values before processing them. Sorry I can’t advise on Java, but am more familiar with PHP so giving the best advice I can based on the issue you are presenting.

Comment: The "can't" is from the input from what I put into the form @jakegould. I'm not using can't in my insert statement, it was pass back from the form to the jsp as a string variable, where it'll insert into the database as a varchar.

Comment: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 't_date' at row 1 sooooo, i just chnaged it back to NOW() and now I don't get the exception thrown..